# How to copy the file in ADF if target container doesn't have files?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to copy data from source to sink if target container does not have any file in it.

I used get meta data activity and filter activity. But this doesn't give me expected output.

Comment: Try using **If activity** instead of filter activity.

Comment: Give the expression as `@equals(length(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems),0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `IF activity` and give the expression as `@equals(length(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems),0)` to check if the target has no file. I reproduced this and below is the approach.

- Get Metadata activity is taken and child items is taken as an argument. This will give the list of files or folders present in the datastore.

[image]

- If activity is taken and checked if the length of the list generated by metadata activity is greater than zero.
  `@equals(length(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems),0)`

[image]

- In true section, you can add copy activity to copy data from source to sink.

By this way, you can get your requirement.